# What is the difference between searching for intermodular calls and searching for names/labels in OllyDBG?

Tags: debugging, assembly, ollydbg

What is the difference between searching for intermodular calls and searching for names/labels in OllyDBG? As far as I can tell, it looks like searching for names just finds the place where a library is maybe imported in the program whereas searching for intermodular calls finds the locations of all calls to those imported functions (which still seems like it's the same thing to me so I must be wrong.)

Answer (score 0):

Eventhough this question is from 2013, some people might still like an answer.

```
Intermodular calls:
= Displays Address
+ Displays Disassembly (e.g. "call <jmp.&kernel32.CreateThread>")
= Displays Destination ("Name" in Names)

Names:
= Displays Address
+ Displays Section (e.g. ".idata")
+ Displays Type (Import / Export)
= Displays Name ("Destination" in intermodular calls)
+ Allows to toggle search between "current module" and "all modules".
```

Other than that, it's pretty much the same.